# Query for all paths to all nodes in closure table with multiple parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a closure table where multiple parents are possible with the associated data table looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [data] (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE closure (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [src_id] int,
    [dst_id] int,
    [depth] int,
    FOREIGN KEY ([src_id]) REFERENCES [data](id),
    FOREIGN KEY ([dst_id]) REFERENCES [data](id)
)
```

Now I created some testdata looking like this with DDL looking like this:

**Data table**

```
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data1')
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data2')
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data3')
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data4')
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data5')
INSERT [data] ([name]) VALUES (N'data6')
```

**Closure table**

```
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 1, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (2, 2, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (3, 3, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (4, 4, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (5, 5, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (6, 6, 0)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 2, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (2, 5, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 5, 2)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (5, 6, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (2, 6, 2)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 6, 3)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 3, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (3, 4, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 4, 2)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (4, 5, 1)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (3, 5, 2)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 5, 3)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (4, 6, 2)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (3, 6, 3)
INSERT [closure] ([src_id], [dst_id], [depth]) VALUES (1, 6, 4)
```

Now what I would want is a query, which outputs every path for every dataset until there is no more `src_id` for that path,
which I wanted to query with this statement:

```
;WITH hierarchy_cte AS (
    SELECT [data].id, [data].name, CAST ([data].name AS VARCHAR(100)) AS path , 0 as pathDepth  
    FROM closure
    INNER JOIN [data]
    ON [data].id = closure.src_id
    WHERE closure.depth = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT closure.src_id, hierarchy_cte.name, CAST(([srcdata].name + ' / ' + hierarchy_cte.path) AS VARCHAR(100)) , hierarchy_cte.pathDepth + 1
    FROM closure    
    INNER JOIN [data] srcdata
    ON srcdata.id = closure.src_id 
    INNER JOIN [data]
    ON [data].id = closure.dst_id
    inner join [hierarchy_cte]
    ON [data].id = hierarchy_cte.id
    AND closure.depth = 1
) 
SELECT * FROM hierarchy_cte
```

**The result looks like this:**

```
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | name  |                 path                  | pathDepth |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | data1 | data1                                 |         0 |
|  2 | data2 | data2                                 |         0 |
|  3 | data3 | data3                                 |         0 |
|  4 | data4 | data4                                 |         0 |
|  5 | data5 | data5                                 |         0 |
|  6 | data6 | data6                                 |         0 |
|  5 | data6 | data5 / data6                         |         1 |
|  2 | data6 | data2 / data5 / data6                 |         2 |
|  4 | data6 | data4 / data5 / data6                 |         2 |
|  3 | data6 | data3 / data4 / data5 / data6         |         3 |
|  1 | data6 | data1 / data3 / data4 / data5 / data6 |         4 |
|  1 | data6 | data1 / data2 / data5 / data6         |         3 |
|  2 | data5 | data2 / data5                         |         1 |
|  4 | data5 | data4 / data5                         |         1 |
|  3 | data5 | data3 / data4 / data5                 |         2 |
|  1 | data5 | data1 / data3 / data4 / data5         |         3 |
|  1 | data5 | data1 / data2 / data5                 |         2 |
|  3 | data4 | data3 / data4                         |         1 |
|  1 | data4 | data1 / data3 / data4                 |         2 |
|  1 | data3 | data1 / data3                         |         1 |
|  1 | data2 | data1 / data2                         |         1 |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I thought my statement would go along all possible paths and end when there is no more `src_id`. I'm just stuck.
**The result I want to have is:**

```
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | name  |                 path                  | pathDepth |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | data1 | data1                                 |         0 |
|  2 | data2 | data1 / data2                         |         1 |
|  3 | data3 | data1 / data3                         |         1 |
|  4 | data4 | data1 / data3 / data4                 |         2 |
|  5 | data5 | data1 / data3 / data4 / data5         |         3 |
|  5 | data5 | data1 / data2 / data5                 |         2 |
|  6 | data6 | data1 / data3 / data4 / data5 / data6 |         4 |
|  6 | data6 | data1 / data2 / data5 / data6         |         3 |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
```

This query does not seem that hard, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on destination, I added closure.dst_id to the CTE

Then I select everything from hierarchy_cte, and join dst_id with src_id

```
FROM hierarchy_cte
    inner join closure 
    on closure.src_id=hierarchy_cte.dst_id
    AND closure.depth = 1
```

Finally we need to select only roots for first step in CTE. Lets define a root as any node which is not the destination of a closure relation,

```
select * from closure c1
where depth=0
and not exists(select 1 from closure c2 where c2.depth>=1 and c1.src_id=c2.dst_id)
```

or perhaps

```
select * from closure c1
where depth=0
and not exists(select 1 from closure c2 where c2.src_id<>c2.dst_id and c1.src_id=c2.dst_id)
```

Using this we get this final query:

```
;WITH hierarchy_cte AS (
    SELECT [data].id, [data].name, CAST ([data].name AS VARCHAR(100)) AS path , closure.depth as pathDepth, closure.dst_id
    FROM closure
    INNER JOIN [data]
    ON [data].id = closure.src_id
    WHERE closure.depth = 0
    and not exists(select 1 from closure c2 where c2.depth>=1 and closure.src_id=c2.dst_id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT hierarchy_cte.id,data.name,CAST ( [hierarchy_cte].path+'/'+ [data].name AS VARCHAR(100)) AS path,pathDepth+1,closure.dst_id
    from [hierarchy_cte] 
    inner join closure 
    on closure.src_id=hierarchy_cte.dst_id
    and closure.depth=1
    INNER JOIN [data] srcdata
    ON srcdata.id = closure.src_id 
    INNER JOIN [data]
    ON [data].id = closure.dst_id
) 
SELECT id,name,path,pathDepth FROM hierarchy_cte
order by path
```

Comment: this does not seem to give the result I was hoping for.

Comment: Sorry - I tried to clean it up but messed it up, try the query I updated above

Comment: Ok cool, this gives the correct result, but only when you know that the root is data1. The query should also work when there are multiple roots and the rootname is not given :/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I know i left in the commented where clause with path1, that was just to replicate the partial listing you had.

I get 21 paths from the query above, with data1.data2,..,data6 acting as root.

What answer do you want form the query besides that?

Comment: Ah I think know where you got me wrong. The last listing I gave is the exact result I want to have. So in the end it should be 8 paths.

Comment: OK, I think the issue is the start condition in the CTE. We take everything with a path depth of 0, which becomes roots!
What we want is to identify everything that is a "true" root.
I would do something like this:
select * from closure c1 where depth=0 and not exists(select 1 from closure c2 where c2.depth>=1 and c1.src_id=c2.dst_id)

To find the roots - what I am doing is assuming tha a root is defined by not being the destination of any closure relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230070/discussion-between-soren-kongstad-and-madibat).